# Math integration assertion, is it true?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am reading about calculus online and I have formulated the following assertion.  Is my assertion true or false? They talk about definite integrals, and how we can solve them via integration and then some theorem where I can solve these problems by subtracting the upper limit from the lower limit.  But I am just wondering if the below is also true? It makes sense to me, but I am not sure.

$$f(b) - f(a) = \sum_{a}^{v}(f' * \frac{b - a}{v})$$

Where v is some large value near infinity.

Comment: What is $f'$ being evaluated at?

Comment: f' is the derivative of f in this case.  I am not sure what the question is? But there is no value for f or f(b) or f(a) because they are the same function. EDIT: And it is just a generic idea kind of question.  So we can say that f(x) = x^2 and f' is the derivative of that so 2x

Comment: Perhaps I'm most confused by what the index is in that summation.  Right now, it doesn't appear that there is one, in which case the sum is simply $f' \cdot\frac{(b-a)(v-a-1)}{v}$

Comment: Oh, the index would start at a in this case and it would increment until v by really small chunks of $\frac{b - a}{v}$

Comment: Hopefully the following captures what you mean by the right hand side: $\lim_{v \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^v f' \left( a + \frac{i}{v}(b - a) \right) \cdot \frac{b-a}{v}$. If so, then yes, this is true. It's because the right side is the limit of some Riemann sums of $f'$, so by definition, it's the definite integral of $f'$. And the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us $\int_a^b f'(x)~dx = f(b) - f(a)$.

Comment: @Jason, I don't think you understand what I'm getting at: you don't have an index appearing in the sum, so it's simply a constant that you're taking the sum of $v-a-1$ times.  Henry's sum does have an index, $i$, and his sum gives one of the common definitions of the Riemann Integral

Comment: I think HenrySwanson is right, though the expression in the question looks pretty different from what Henry wrote...